# Heatmap out of 3D array

Tags: arrays, julia, heatmap

I’m kind of desperate, I have a 3D array formated like x,y,z and i want to show the z value in a squared heatmap. The columns are sorted like x:aaabbbccc, y:abcabcabc (but not just with 3 values, instead 600). How am I converting the array, that pcolor is doing it like the way I want, with the right x and y values also (not just enumerating them).

Best,
Hannes

Comment: Try to add more details to the question. For example, adding some code or output from what you have already is good. Or add a small example of the "3D" array (it is probably just a 2D array of z-values).

Comment: Please follow @DanGetz's advise and provide some starter code to make things more concrete. Your question is not clear enough. From what I understood, all you need is `plot(x, y', z)` with `Plots.jl`.

Comment: Double posted: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/3d-array-to-heatmap/8579

Comment: Yeah sorry, all I wanted was a pcolor/pcolormesh plot out of it with cmap="jet", I managed to do it with a transformation of the 3D Matrix to a squared 2D Matrix. I red a bit and could not find a function in Julia to do so, so I wrote my own. For the x-y-labeling I wrote my own aswell. Thx anyways